# How to add a parameter to a method inherited by many classes

Tags: java, eclipse, interface, automated-refactoring

I am using eclipse and have an interface that is used by many of my classes. Right now, I'd like to add a variable(parameter) to one of the methods in the interface but I don't want to have to go through all of my classes to add the variable manually to each method when I may not even be using that variable in all of those classes.

Is there an easy and quick way to do this without having to do it all manually?

Example:

```
public interface Screen {
    public void render(GameContainer arg0, Graphics g) throws SlickException;
}
```

I would like to add the parameter ResourcePack like this:

```
public interface Screen {
    public void render(GameContainer arg0, Graphics g, ResourcePack pack) throws SlickException;
}
```

I would like it to add another parameter and have it update all the classes that inherit this method with that parameter so I don't have to do this manually.

Comment: you mean you want to add a parameter to the function? In that case [method-signature refactoring](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-refactor.htm) should (I haven't worked with eclipse for some time to be honest) work.

Comment: Provide some code to illustrate your problem.

Comment: I posted some code in the edit so hopefully that can help.

Answer (score 3):

Place the cursor on the method and  enter : `Shift + Alt + C`. 
You would have a wizard to change the signature of the method (add, remove, edit and order change).
A thing that may be important when you a add a new argument is choosing a default value when it is called.

Here is a simple guide line :

- If `null` is an acceptable default value, keep `null`.
- If you have a unique way to define the default value from callers, fill this value as needed.
- If you want to be sure that the value is filled by you, don't let the `null` value as default value but enter something which doesn't compile in order to be sure that you will have to edit the caller of the method.

Comment: I've found that Ctrl+Alt+C doesn't do any thing but Shift+Alt+C brings up the wizard. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Indeed, little mistake from my part :)